# openshift-origin add secret for gcr.io

Tags: openshift-origin, google-container-registry

I've trying all day to add a secret for access to a private registry on gcr.io. ( Google Cloud Registry)

The documentation from gcr has some info about a json key file.

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://eu.gcr.io
```

This creates an entry in the ~/.docker/config.json. If I locally then try to pull from the registry it works.

I've tried the following in openshift to add the secret

```
oc secrets new gcr .dockerconfigjson="~/.docker/config.json"
oc secrets add serviceaccount/default secrets/gcr --for=pull
oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/gcr
```

And

```
oc secrets new-dockercfg gcr --docker-server=eu.gcr.io --docker-username=_json_key --docker-password="$(cat ~/Downloads/key.json)" --docker-email=web@gcr.com
oc secrets add serviceaccount/default secrets/gcr --for=pull
oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/gcr
```

This always results in the following

```
$ oc new-app eu.gcr.io/webshops/shop-1
error: can't look up Docker image "eu.gcr.io/webshops/shop-1": Internal error occurred: error retrieving repository: server returned 403
error: no match for "eu.gcr.io/webshops/shop-1"
```

Am I doing something wrong to access the eu.gcr.io from openshift?

Comment: We will take a look at what the server is sending - what you provided looks correct.

Comment: @Clayton do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker login` command uses `https://gcr.io`, what if you log into `https://eu.gcr.io` and try the first approach?

Comment: It was typo from me. But just to be sure I've tried it again as you suggested. But still the same error occurs.